# Store type in variable

Tags: swift

I simplified my code. So now I have a generic function like this:

```
func genFunc<T: Codable>(test: T.Type) {
    print(test)
}
```

Let's define a dummy struct:

```
struct Test: Codable {
    let name: String
}
```

Now I can call the function with this:

```
genFunc(test: Test.self)
```

But what I want to do is to save the type and call the function with the stored type. This code is not working:

```
var type: Codable.Type
type = Test.self
genFunc(test: type)
```

I get the error: `Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred`

Comment: You will not have actually simplified your code if what you actually need are overloads. A generic function requires a concrete type or metatype. `Codable.self` is not that.

Comment: @Jessy: by simplifying I mean that I removed parameters and properties and I renamed everything. What do you mean with overloads?